# How can I navigate to another page after CircularProgressIndicator completed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

Hello I am new in Flutter and I am currently building a chat application.
I got a profile maker screen where the user can upload an image to set their avatar. I am using `CircularProgressIndicator()` to show an uploading screen. I want to know that how can I navigate to the next screen i.e my main homescreen automatically after uploading completed so that the user doesn't have to wait for any button to press.

Here is the code which I tried

```dart
progressString != '100% Completed' ? Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                  ),
                   Text("Uploading File : $progressString",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white54,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                           ),
                          ),
                         ],
                        ) : Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                 return LoginPage();
                              }),
                            ),
```

Upload Code

```
FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    "username": userName.toString(),
    "name": naMe.toString(),
    "birthday": birthDay.toString(),
    "about": aboutUser.toString(),
    "sender": sendUser.toString(),
    "mobile": userMobile.toString(),
    "avatar": _image != null
        ? await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image.path,
            filename: avatarName.toString())
        : Text('Invalid Avatar'),
  });

  if (_validateAndSave()) {
    final token = widget.token;

    try {
      Dio dio = Dio();
      dio.options.headers['Accept'] = "application/json";
      dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $token";
      dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data";
      dio.options.followRedirects = false;

      var response = await dio.post(url,
          data: data, onSendProgress: (int rec, int total) {
        setState(() {
          uploading = true;
          progressString = ((rec / total * 100).toString());
        });
      });

      var responseCode = response.statusCode;
      print('Dio responseCode : $responseCode');

 } on DioError catch (err) {
      var responseCode = err.response.statusCode;
      print(responseCode);
    }

 setState(() {
      uploading = false;
      progressString = "100% Completed ";
      print(progressString);
    });
  }
```

Comment: add your code then we can help you

Comment: Can You Please Help Now.....     I attached the code which I tried...

Comment: How you upload  image to server?

Comment: I use formdata and multipartfile to upload image and a form

Comment: add your upload method codes

Comment: where you set your progressString to '100%  Completed' ?

Comment: after the Dio catch error method, I set a state for the progressString to 100% Completed.

Comment: Any one please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set your navigator inside of your upload function after upload finished

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
         CircularProgressIndicator(
             backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
         ),
         SizedBox(
             height: 20.0,
         ),
         Text("Uploading File : $progressString",
              style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.white54,
                   fontSize: 20.0,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              ),
         ),
     ],
),
```

```
FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    "username": userName.toString(),
    "name": naMe.toString(),
    "birthday": birthDay.toString(),
    "about": aboutUser.toString(),
    "sender": sendUser.toString(),
    "mobile": userMobile.toString(),
    "avatar": _image != null
        ? await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image.path,
            filename: avatarName.toString())
        : Text('Invalid Avatar'),
  });

  if (_validateAndSave()) {
    final token = widget.token;

    try {
      Dio dio = Dio();
      dio.options.headers['Accept'] = "application/json";
      dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $token";
      dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data";
      dio.options.followRedirects = false;

      var response = await dio.post(url,
          data: data, onSendProgress: (int rec, int total) {
        setState(() {
          uploading = true;
          progressString = ((rec / total * 100).toString());
        });
      });

      var responseCode = response.statusCode;
      print('Dio responseCode : $responseCode');

 } on DioError catch (err) {
      var responseCode = err.response.statusCode;
      print(responseCode);
    }

      Future.delaye(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){
          Navigator.pushReplacement(this.context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return LoginPage();
             }),
          );
      });
  }
```

Comment: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Comment: this type of error occurs after putting navigator inside the upload function after upload finished.

Comment: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Comment: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Comment: Thank You, Veneno. You made it what I want Thankx a lot buddy.....

Answer (score 0):

When the upload is complete, update the UI to show the user that the upload is complete ***and*** add a post frame callback to navigate to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create a new file i.e, splashscreen.dart file under lib folder. In main.dart file give reference to SplashScreen().

Filename: main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mfitz/splashscreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Step 2: Under splashscreen.dart file create the required UI for the splash screen and include the following code under void initState() method to navigate to the new screen after 5 seconds.

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen()));
```

**Splash Screen Code**

Filename: splashscreen.dart

```
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    
    import 'mainScreen.dart';
    
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
//Navigates to new screen after 5 seconds.
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen()));
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/img2.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                            radius: 80.0,
                            child: Text(
                              "MOBIFIT.",
                              style: GoogleFonts.aldrich(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 30.0),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100.0, left: 100.0),
                            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              valueColor:
                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              minHeight: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0))
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**SPLASHSCREEN**
[image: Splashscreen along with Linear Progress Indicator]

**MAINSCREEN**
[image]